# Type property value enforced from keys of another property with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

The following examples describes the problem :

```
type TestType = {
  properties: {
    [x: string]: number;
  };
  defaultProperty: string;
};

const invalid: TestType = {
  properties: {
    foo: 123,
  },
  defaultProperty: "not a valid property",
};

const valid: TestType = {
  properties: {
    foo: 123,
  },
  defaultProperty: "foo",
};
```

In summary, I'm looking to create a type where `defaultProperty` value is enforced to be a valid value from the `properties` object.

In the above example, `invalid` is wrong because `defaultProperty` value is not a valid key from `properties`.

Is this possible with TypeScript?

I have tried

```
type TestType<P = { [p: string]: number }> = {
  properties: P;
  defaultProperty: keyof P;
};
```

but it does not error the `invalid` value. In fact, `defaultProperty` is of type `string | number`, which is definitely not what I expected it to be.

Comment: You need to make it generic and use a function to infer the generic parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're open to using a function to make the object, it's trivial with a generic function.

```js
type TestType<P extends Record<any, any> = Record<any, any>> = {
  properties: P;
  defaultProperty: P extends infer R ? keyof R: never;
};

const makeTest = <T,>(properties: T, defaultKey: keyof T) => {
    return {properties ,defaultKey}
}

const invalid = 
makeTest( {
    foo: 123,
  },
 "not a valid property",)
;

const valid = makeTest({
    foo: 123,
  },
  "foo",
);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbggHgApQgD2BAdgCbxQBKEAxgPYBOhqAhviADRRMgB8UAvGZbXoc2HTtz4BvAFBQoYGlUg1gASwQAuKOgDcMqIQgAzBgFcANsHQKloTZhx4iJFfkMQaZKAH4oAawggVIZkmvgQAG7uugC+ulLU+IhQALYM-nBJfKgwLJwAFPKK7qoasGwGxubAANIBmv6BwTAAlLzc0rKyNBDAJjT4UBKFNmokLBWmFrUg0VKz8VSJwFAu4QxmKoS8UFKp6QjAeYN6soZUVJoAjABMAMwsetEPUABE+FTLDFBrG1vDxSAXixmlI4gkkj9Nts9hAMocOp0zhcoDd7o9nq8kUCpM1tEA)

If you don't want to use a function, you can do what I've given below making the type generic. Personally, I think it's an uglier solution because of the repeated types.

```js
type TestType<P extends Record<string, any>> = {
  properties: P;
  defaultProperty: keyof P;
};


const invalid: TestType<{foo: number}> = {
  properties: {
    foo: 123,
  },
  defaultProperty: "not a valid property",
};

const valid: TestType<{foo: number}> = {
  properties: {
    foo: 123,
  },
  defaultProperty: "foo",
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbggHgApQgD2BAdgCbxQBKEAxgPYBOhqiNAlvgOYA0UAhviAHx8oAXigBvAFBQoYGlUg1gTBAC4o6ANySohCADMuAVwA2wdLPmhVAawggqutZoC+m8eOr5EUFgDcuRpkJVOERkSFRRXSoqVXwDAFsAIwgaJ0ERCSkZORTFFTEtKSiYqABGACYAZnYtJxqpHX1jU3NckFUAInwqYG4oPwDCaVaFEA6alzcPLwHA4IQkFAji2ITk1PSCrJG8+FVMqSgVsqr6qDqtRsMTMxzRzuLx8RcgA)

Comment: This is a solution that I will definitely considerate. Thank you!